# Encrypting the ReturnURL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, returnurl

I am wondering if its possible to encrypt the `ReturnURl` before it's displayed to the end user.

I am pretty new at .NET, but I have tried using the PostAuthenticateRequest in the Global.asax.  But that doesnt seem to ever fire.

I would be using my own encryption logic if this is even possible.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "encode"?  Are you worried about query parameters in the return url?

Comment: this was inherited code, and per our standards is to encrypt any URL parameters.

Comment: would love to man...out of my control at the moment

Comment: What kind of encryption are we talking here? RSA with keys from your key store? Something symetric like AES? Where do you want to store the key? Does it have to be decrypted?

Comment: We have an internal encryption component.  It would be decrypted, preferably, in the code behind

Answer (score 3):

The only reason you would want to do this is if you have sensitive information in the URL.

And if you have sensitive data in the URL --

**Don't.**

And also, don't use your own encryption logic.  Someone else has already done the heavy lifting for you.  This is definitely one area you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

.NET includes plenty of ways to encrypt your data.

[A .NET Cryptography Primer](http://statestreetgang.net/post/2008/04/A-NET-Cryptography-Primer2c-Part-One.aspx)

Comment: There isn't and sensitive data in the URL.

Comment: this was inherited code, and per our standards is to encrypt any URL parameters.

Comment: we actually have our own core component to do encryption